Swipeable List data Kotlin
I want to implement a swipeable card that will allow a user to swipe forward and back through all the data in a List and for them to be able to enter a Qty in an open field, that i can then update the list with the entered qty.
What would be the best way to do this? Would it be a Recycler view with added code? ViewPager2? Or something else?
